# jQuery setTimeout() Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS and facing some challenges which may seem simple.

what i want to do is:

1. a user clicks on a button that states 'submit'
2. when the button is clicked the word 'submit' changes to 'please wait...' & button is disabled
3. the button is disabled for 2 seconds
4. after 2 seconds the word 'please submit..' changes back to 'submit' & the button becomes activated (its no longer disabled)

i have written the below code. Any advise on this would be much appreciated

html

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit_wide" id="myBtn" >
</form>
```

javascript

```
$(".submit_wide").click(function () {
    $(this).val('Please wait..');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        $(this).val('Submit');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` is out of scope inside `setTimeout` trying setting `$(this)` to a variable outside of setTimeout and using that instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The problem is that inside the `setTimeout()` call, `this` doesn't refer to the button. You need to set a variable to keep the reference to the button.

I've created a sample below. See how I use the variable named `$this`.

```js
$(".submit_wide").click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.val('Please wait..');
    $this.attr('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $this.attr('disabled', false);
        $this.val('Submit');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="submit_wide" value="Submit"/>
```

**UPDATE:**
Now with modern browsers supporting [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you can use them to avoid altering the `this` context. See updated snippet below.

```js
$(".submit_wide").click(function () {
    $(this).val('Please wait..');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(() => { 
        $(this).attr('disabled', false);
        $(this).val('Submit');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="submit_wide" value="Submit"/>
```